# Can ADF Custom Sink Ordering be use to load parent records first and then child?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

***Update:*** Microsoft have identified the problem and will be fixing it!

I am attempting to use Azure Data Factory to load a parent and child table in Azure SQL, which is enforced in the database by a foreign key.

My DataFlow is very simple, reading from staging tables and writing 1-for-1 into the destination tables. One of the reads has an exists constraint against a third table to ensure that only the correct subset of records are loaded.

I have two very similar DataFlows loading two kinds of record with similar parent-child relationships, one of them works just fine, the other fails with a foreign key violation. Sometimes. It's not consistent, and changing seemingly unrelated things such as refreshing a Dataset schema sometimes makes it work.

Both DataFlows have Custom Sink Ordering set to make the parent table insert happen first at Order 1, and the child record happen at Order 2.

Am I using this feature correctly, is this something that Custom Sink Ordering should give me?

This is the job layout, it's actually loading two child tables:
[image: Azure Data Factory flow loading a parent table and two child tables]

I tried removing the top sink, so it only loads the Write Order 1 table (sinkSSUSpatialUnit) and the Write Order 2 table (sinkSSUCompartment) that is failing with a foreign key violation, and the problem does not happen in that cut-down clone of the DataFlow.

Microsoft have found a problem with Custom Sink Order not working as intended intermittently, and will be fixing it. I will update this if I find out any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support have said that if you have a parent table with Write Order 1, and two child tables with Write Order 2, then it might go wrong.

The answer is to set one of the child tables to Write Order 3, so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Do you have a source for where MSFT said that, or where you see that write order 3 avoids ambiguity?

Comment: It was said in response to a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, MS does not say anything about the order of the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#custom-sink-ordering

Maybe yo can try to use the read committed isolation level for the source in order to see if ADF decides to wait to the sink before reading the source dataset.

Comment: I don't care about the order of the sources, @Héctor A. I'm not trying to extract data that got loaded in the same DataFlow. That's another use case that I would be interested in, but I know it's not possible. I just want to load the parent table before the child table. Sources A and B into Sinks X then Y.